# How to run virus scanner script from host machine from Docker container

Tags: docker

I've got a java program where user can upload photos etc. It is running on docker container in Linux. I can have a plenty of containers and I don't want to pay many licenses to Mcafee, so is there a good solution for executing uvscan on host machine and scan uploaded files and buy only one license instead of 30?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best practice but you can mount all your photos folder and scan on the host.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to mount files to host directory and perform scan.

There is a blog which explains scanning malicious files, but it uses Linux Malware Detection (LMD) and CalmAV, go through if it helpful

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/virus-malware-scanning-service-docker-dietrich-rordorf

Comment: I would like to execute virus scanner on host machine  as well, not inside the container. I start scanning from the tomcat, which is running inside the docker container. So if both are on host machine, how to start scanning,via SSH or how? I will check your link.